# Video plugin installation stops in social engine after domain.com/install/manage/query

Tags: socialengine

I am facing an issue with social engine video plugin installation. I have installed some other plugins all were installed well . In the case of video plugin installation process stops in the step domain.com/install/manage/query. It shows a blank white page

I am using 4.7.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try to enable error reporting in the .htaccess file in the SocialEngine's root folder, it may show you some sort of php errors and search for solutions.